# Is the e-Loop for Gate control not supposed to work at night

Tags: gates

I am using a Nice Gate Controller and I purchased a couple of Mini e-LOOP devices to detect a car and open the gate (from inside).  It all works fine during the day.  But the gate does not open at night.

The supplier says "that his supplier says it should work, maybe its too cold".  But it isnt too cold, it is 6°C at 1am.  If this is true then it is useless even for daytime.

[image]

I am hoping that someone else may be using it and could share their experience.

Its a small compact device bolted to the concrete drive and communicates over RF with a little dongle.  The output from the dongle goes to the Gate Controller.  I have 2 of them and they both behave the same way.

[image]

Comment: Wires rule, RF can be flaky.

Comment: To be clear, the eLOOP device detects the car (like a loop in a roadway that controls traffic signals), and it works during the day but not at night? If the supplier says it's too cold, have you tried (temporarily, at least) providing a heater of some sort for it? That would rule out that possibility. Also, what do the mfgr specs say for operating range? That's where the real answer to your question is. As this question stands, though, asking "to share experiences" seems very broad and open-ended, potentially off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Try powering down any LED or CFL lights in the vicinity that run at night, including any that work by darkness or motion detection. These lights sometimes interfere with garage door openers, some of which work in the same 433 MHz radio band.

LED lights that are supposed to be "garage door opener safe" are said to be available, and may also allow your device to work at night.